# How to Internationalize Wordpress - Extract strings with textdomains, per textdomain individually

Tags: php, localization

I spent several hours searching, and have not found a solution, how to extract Strings dedicated by Textdomain from a PHP File (in a wordpress plugin):

In my plugin and theme I use for example

```
__('This should be internationalized Module A','MyTextdomain-A');
__('This should be internationalized Module B','MyTextdomain-B');
```

I have no problem extracting this via PoEdit (which seems to be the standard). It will all endup in one(!!) .pot file. But this is not what i want.

I want the "Extractor" only to extract all Strings from Textdomain **A** **or** Textdomain **B individually**, but not both together.

How can I solve this. This seems to be an absolutely trival requirement, but I have not found a solution yet.

**UPDATE:** Why is this so important? Because in a standard Application you have for example lots of Backend Text. This is unnecessary to be loaded in Frontend-Calls ans saves a lot of RAM. Separating is key here. And even in single files you might want to split messages in a "BASE" and "CUSTOM" file (one that is shared the otherone changable by users etc). Whithout extracting by Textdomain individually, this is not possible to do efficiently.

Thanks very much

Comment: There is a discussion on woocommerces' github about splitting language files with reference to a WP file called makepot.php that will split them. Maybe this code will direct you? https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/issues/2051

Comment: Thanks very much! Heard of makepots.php but didn't investigate it then. Thanks to your hint I looked at the source now. I am not shure (its not documented at all) it allows parsing the context but looks like it is not used for the context I want. But then "hacking" the code should be possible. Thanks, you can post it as answer, I will tick it as accepted.

Comment: Ok, i'll make the comment a post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a discussion on woocommerces' github about splitting language files with reference to a WP file called makepot.php that will split them. Maybe this code will direct you? github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/issues/2051